# React Native Ruby version error even If I have the correct version installed

Tags: ruby, react-native

- I am trying to create a new React Native Project using npx. The whole
  npx process is getting failed due to Ruby version. Check the attached
  image for more details.
- The Ruby version was already updated using
  rbenv. You can see the Ruby version in the image attached.
- I have
  also added the necessary code to the .bash_profile and .zshrc files.
  Restarted the terminal and system multiple times but the error is the
  same.

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

[image: Terminal Image]

Comment: take reference from here to finish your ruby setup https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv

Answer (score 0):

First use `rbenv` for the ruby setup. I'll recommend to restart the system once done with the ruby setup. take help from [here](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv).

Then follow these steps to create the react native project.

```
1. npx react-native init testproject --skip-install

2. cd testproject

3. yarn install

4. cd ios

5. bundle install (For Intel Chip)
   arch -arm64 bundle install (For M1 Chip)

6. bundle exec pod install (For Intel Chip)
   arch -arm64 bundle exec pod install (For M1 Chip)
```

Comment: This works! But I now have other issues like "We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65". I tried some Stackoverflow solutions but nothing changed.

Comment: If it works this way then what's the problem when directly installed using npx. Ruby version is updated and rbenv is installed correctly.