# React Native doesn't recognize the ruby version of rvm

Tags: ruby, react-native, rubygems

I'm trying to correct the issue in my react native setup, the issue seems to be ruby.
To clarify I'm on a Mac M1

So i installed rvm, installed rvm 2.7.6 (which is the current version of ruby react native uses, information taken on their website). I did this command on Rosetta2 because it was crashing in a non-rosetta terminal : `rvm install 2.7.6`

The rest of the command are NOT done in Rosetta2.

Then I added rvm to the my ~/.zshrc file

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.6/bin"
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"
```

well actually, I added those two lines with the command `rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles`

Sometimes, I still get this error, I have to admit that I don't know why, I understood that the line above was supposed to add it to the path. `Warning! PATH is not properly set up, /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.6/bin is not at first place.`

Anyway, I do this then :

```
rvm --default use 2.7.6
ruby --version
```

the last line return this : `ruby 2.7.6p219 (2022-04-12 revision c9c2245c0a) [x86_64-darwin22]`

which sounds okay to me, so I try to init a new project with react native : `npx react-native init NewProject`

Then I got something suspicious, react native telling me to download cocoapods either with gem or home-brew, but I already did it with gem. Anyway I select download with gem (or Homebrew, both result have the same error). And I got this error : `Your Ruby version is 2.6.10, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.6`

Re-checked the ruby version, still the 2.7.6, I'm missing something, and maybe more than just one thing but I've been on a lot of post and stuff and can't find the solution so I'm trying here.

Comment: Installing RVM and Ruby using Rosetta was a mistake. My recommendation: completely remove RVM and start over. I don't recommend you use RVM. Use [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) or [asdf](https://asdf-vm.com/) and do not use Rosetta. **Follow the setup instructions exactly and with great care**. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74942677/3784008) likely explains your error message about `Your Ruby version is 2.6.10`. My very short answer is: you are not carefully and exactly following the setup instructions for Ruby or for React Native. Start over and follow the instructions.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to remove the `/usr/local/bin/bundle` file and then run again ?

source : https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35873#issuecomment-1397226452

Here are some alternative you can try too :

- Tutorial for ruby with rbenv : https://nnomadic.medium.com/how-to-address-problems-with-ruby-cocoapods-and-react-native-cli-on-m1-macbooks-88804f6de06
- Workaround with rbenv : [React Native Ruby version error even If I have the correct version installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74615169/react-native-ruby-version-error-even-if-i-have-the-correct-version-installed)
- Installing cocoapods (after ruby is installed) : [How do I install CocoaPods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20755044/how-do-i-install-cocoapods)

Comment: I just tried, the init works but I can't run it later. It gave me an error 65 about Xcode. 

It stills asks me to install CocoaPods EVERY time I init a new project so I don't think it's actually the good solution.